# Upload de imagem com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

### Como fazer upload de imagem usando Jquery?

Essa é uma dúvida que anda me perseguindo por muito tempo, espero que vocês possam me ajudar.

Bom, andei pesquisando e vi que tem um plugin para isso, ajaxForm. Porem não encontro estrutura para usa-lo, na própria página tem uns exemplos mas tive a capacidade de não entender como fazer.

Tem também o FormData que não sei de onde é, vou pesquisar. Se puderem me ajudar com um desses dois, o que for mais viável e fácil. Ficarei muito agradecido.

Agradeço desde já!

(Uma ótima forma de me ajudar seria com a estrutura do que forem de dar de exemplo, assim poderei aprender olhando como se faz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente

Crie um página com uma tag **form** e coloque dois elementos ***input*** do tipo `file` e um ***button*** do tipo `button`. Não esqueça de fazer a referencia do JQuery na sua página. Como demonstrado nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="file" name="fileimagem" id="fileimagem" />
        <button type="button" id="btn">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").on('click', function(){

                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('fileimagem', $('#fileimagem')[0].files[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'save.php',
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Após a criação da página agora crie o script no PHP bem simples para gravar a imagem em algum diretório dentro da sua applicação Web.

```
<?php   

    if (!empty($_FILES['fileimagem']))
    {
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileimagem']['tmp_name'], 'img/'.$_FILES['fileimagem']['name']);       
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
```

***Boa Leitura:***

[1 - move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

[2 - Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

[3 - FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData)

[4 - jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: No data append vc passa 2 parametros. O que seria o primeiro e o segundo? me indica algum documento pra ler ou é coisa simples e vc me fala

Comment: O primeiro parâmetro seria o nome para que eu possa recuperar na programação (exemplo `$_FILES['fileimagem']`) e o segundo é o conteudo do file para enviar para o servidor que no caso é a imagem escolhida !!! Qualquer dúvida estamos ai.

Comment: @PedroSoares mais sobre o assunto em [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: Espero que ainda possa esta me ajudando. Estou com um problema :(

Quando eu coloco:

var data = new FormData();
data.append('fileimagem', $('#fileimagem')[0].files[0]);

A requisição ajax para de funcionar, se eu remover e passar outro valor em data ele funciona normal. sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Acho que com isso que esta me passando vou finalmente conseguir

Comment: Relação `<input type="file" name="fileimagem" id="fileimagem" />` com `$('#fileimagem')` está é a relação com JQuery pegando e acessando aquela tag input do tipo file (que é a imagem) mas, no JQuery você precisa informar `$('#fileimagem')[0].files[0]` no segundo parâmetro para funcionar. Eu não sei bem como está seu código mas, a relação é essa.

Comment: Entendi, porem meu codigo esta travando no js quando eu crio um new FormData();

Tem algum por que disso?

Comment: Fiz alguns teste e na real é esta linha que esta travando

data.append('fileimagem', $('#fileimagem')[0].files[0]);

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40300/discussion-between-pedro-soares-and-joao).

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que use o [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). Bastante popular, com boa documentação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código fonte:

```
<div id="uploader">
    <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    // Setup html5 version
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url : "/examples/upload",
         
        chunk_size : '1mb',
        rename : true,
        dragdrop: true,
         
        filters : {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size : '10mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
            ]
        },
 
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {
            width : 200,
            height : 200,
            quality : 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },
 
 
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
     
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'
    });
});
</script>
```