# imagem aparece no explorer mas não dá para visualizar

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Estou fazendo um upload de arquivos com **html5**, **ajax** e **php**.

Tudo vai bem, a gravação no banco é feita, o upload é feito, mas a imagem, quando vê ela no windows explorer, ainda que ela esteja lá, mas não dá para visualiza-la.

O nome está correto, está com a extensão.

Está parecendo uma falha do **uploader**.

O que pode ser feito?

Segue o código:

FORM

```
<div class="plano">

  <h1 class="titulos">Cadastro de Plano</h1>

  <form method="post" class="planoCadastrar"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="nomePlano" id="nomePlano" class="typeTextMedio" placeholder="Nome"  required /><br /><br />

    <textarea placeholder="Descrição" class="textarea" name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="93" rows="15" required></textarea><br /> <br />

    <div id="multiple_upload">
        <input type="hidden" id="arquivos" name="arquivos" />
        <input type="file" multiple 
               id="fotos" 
               name="fotos[]"
               accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpg, image/png" />
        <div id="message">Selecionar fotos</div> 
        <div id="lista"></div>
    </div>          

    <img class="spinner" src="../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif" />          
    <input type="submit" class="btnAcesso" value="Enviar" />

    <label class="resposta"></label>

  </form><br /><br />

  <script> 
    $('.elevate-image').ezPlus({
        zoomType: 'inner',
        cursor: 'crosshair'     
    });
  </script>  

</div>
```

JQuery

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoEditar").on("submit", function() {

        var idPlano   = $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoEditar input[type=hidden]#idPlano").val();
        var nomePlano = $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoEditar input[type=text]#nomePlano").val();
        var descricao = $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoEditar textarea#descricao").val();

        if ( nomePlano == "" || 
             idPlano   == "" || 
             descricao == "") {

            alert("Algum campo está vazio!");

            return false;

        } 
        $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoEditar input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'none');
        $("div.conteudo div.plano.planoEditar form img").css('display', 'block');

        $("div.conteudo div.plano form input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'none');
        $("div.conteudo div.plano form img").css('display', 'block');

        var formData = new FormData(this); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "../_requeridos/editaPlano.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            beforeSend: function() {               
            },
            success: function (retorno) {

               $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoEditar input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'block');
               $("div.conteudo div.plano.planoEditar form img").css('display', 'none');

                if (retorno == 1) {
                  resposta = "Plano cadastrado com sucesso!";   
                } else {
                  resposta = "Erro no cadastro do Plano";
                }
                $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
                $(".resposta").html(resposta);     

            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

php

```
<?php
    require_once "../_controles/_conexao/Conexao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_util/PhpUtil.php";     
    require_once "../_controles/_util/Constantes.php";      
    require_once "../_controles/_models/Planos.php";    
    require_once "../_controles/_models/Fotos.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_models/Upload.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/PlanosDao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/FotosDao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/UploadDao.php";

    $connection = new Conexao(); 
    $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();
    $phpUtil = new PhpUtil(); 
    $constantes = new Constantes(); 
    $planosDao = new PlanosDao($conexao);
    $fotosDao = new FotosDao($conexao);

    $nomePlano = $_POST["nomePlano"];   
    $descricao = $_POST["descricao"];   

    $plano = new Planos(                 
                     $nomePlano,
                     $descricao);

    $cadastro = $planosDao->cadastrar($plano);

    $ultimoId = $planosDao->ultimoIdCadastrado();

    require_once "upload.php";  

    echo $cadastro ? 1 : 2;

?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    ///////////////////////////UPLOAD DAS FOTOS////////////////////////////////////       
    $arquivos1 = explode ("|", $_POST["arquivos"]);  
    $arquivos2 = $_FILES["fotos"];
    $arquivos = $fotosDao->arrayFotos($arquivos1, $arquivos2);

    if(sizeof($arquivos))  {

        foreach($arquivos as $fotografia) {

          $upload = new Upload($fotografia, "../_img/_fotos");

          $uploadDao = new UploadDao($upload);

          // tamanho de erro 5MB = 5 * 1024 * 1024 = 5242880
          $erro = $uploadDao->erro(5242880);

          if($erro[0] == 0)   {

              $envio = $uploadDao->uploadFile();                  

              if($envio[0]==0) ;

              $nomeImagem = $upload->getNomeBanco();

          } else {

              $phpUtil->erro($erro[1]);

          }

          $fotosDao->cadastrar ($ultimoId, $upload->getNomeBanco());

        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////UPLOAD DAS FOTOS////////////////////////////////////    
?>
```

Veja como está no **Windows Explorer**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Em tempo:**

**UploadDao.php**

```
<?php

  class UploadDao {

    private $arquivo;


    public function __construct($_upload) {

        $this->arquivo = $_upload;
    }

    /*
      Erros do arquivo;
      erro ($_tamanho)
      Onde  $_tamanho é em bits, ou seja, 5MB - 5 * 1024 * 1024= 
    */
    public function erro ($_tamanho) {

        $mensagem = "Sem erros!";
        $erro = 0;

        if(isset($this->arquivo)) {

            if ( 
                $this->arquivo->getExtensao() != "JPG" &&  
                $this->arquivo->getExtensao() != "jpg" &&  
                $this->arquivo->getExtensao() != "JPEG" &&  
                $this->arquivo->getExtensao() != "jpeg" &&  
                $this->arquivo->getExtensao() != "PNG" && 
                $this->arquivo->getExtensao() != "png"
              ) {

                $mensagem = "Imagem precisa ser nos formatos: jpg, JPG, jpeg, JPEG, png, PNG";

                $erro = 1;

              } else if ($this->arquivo->getTamanho() >= $_tamanho ) {

                $mensagem = "Tamanho máximo da Imagem é de ".($_tamanho/(1024*1024))." MB";

                $erro = 2;

              }

        }

        return array($erro, $mensagem, $this->arquivo->getTamanho()/(1024*1024));
    }

    public function uploadFile() {              

        $erro = 0;
        $mensagem = "Sucesso";

        try {

            $urlEnvio = $this->arquivo->getEndereco()."/".$this->arquivo->getNomeBanco();

             move_uploaded_file($this->arquivo->getNomeTemporario(), $urlEnvio);             

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $erro = 1;
            $mensagem = "falha no envio";
        }

        return array($erro, $mensagem);

    }

    private function geraMiniatura ($_largura, $_url) {             

        //CRIA UMA NOVA IMAGEM
        if( $this->arquivo->getExtensao() == "JPG" ||  $this->arquivo->getExtensao() == "jpg"  ) {

            $imagem_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($this->arquivo->getNomeTemporario());

        } else if( $this->arquivo->getExtensao() == "JPEG" || $this->arquivo->getExtensao() == "jpeg") {

            $imagem_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($this->arquivo->getNomeTemporario());

        } else if( $this->arquivo->getExtensao() == "PNG" || $this->arquivo->getExtensao() == "png") {

            $imagem_orig = ImageCreateFromPNG($this->arquivo->getNomeTemporario());

        }

        //LARGURA
        $pontoX = ImagesX($imagem_orig);
        //ALTURA
        $pontoY = ImagesY($imagem_orig); 

        //DEFINE OS PARÂMETROS DA MINIATURA
        $largura = $_largura;
        $altura = ($pontoY * $largura) / $pontoX;

        //CRIA O THUMBNAIL
        $imagem_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($largura, $altura); 

        //COPIA A IMAGEM ORIGINAL PARA DENTRO
        ImageCopyResampled($imagem_fin, $imagem_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largura+1, $altura+1, $pontoX, $pontoY); 

        //SALVA A IMAGEM
        ImageJPEG($imagem_fin, $_url,100); 

        //LIBERA A MEMÓRIA
        ImageDestroy($imagem_orig);
        ImageDestroy($imagem_fin);

    }


  }
?>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php

 class Upload {

    private $nome;
    private $nomeBanco;
    private $nomeTemporario;
    private $largura;
    private $altura;
    private $tamanho;
    private $endereco;
    private $extensao;


    public function __construct ($_file, $_url) {

        $dimensoes = getimagesize($_file["tmp_name"]);
        $this->extensao = pathinfo($_file["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);         
        $this->nome = $_file["name"];
        $this->nomeBanco = $this->setNomeBanco();
        $this->nomeTemporario = $_file["tmp_name"];
        $this->largura = $dimensoes[0];
        $this->altura = $dimensoes[1];
        $this->tamanho = $_file["size"];
        $this->endereco = $_url;

    }

    public function setNomeBanco () {   
        return md5(uniqid(time())).".". $this->extensao;        
    }   

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getNomeBanco() {
        return $this->nomeBanco;
    }

    public function getNomeTemporario() {
        return $this->nomeTemporario;
    }

    public function getLargura() {
        return $this->largura;
    }

    public function getAltura() {
        return $this->altura;
    }

    public function getTamanho() {
        return $this->tamanho;
    }

    public function getEndereco() {
        return $this->endereco;
    }

    public function getExtensao() {
        return $this->extensao;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Faltou a parte mais importante da questão: qual o código responsável pelo *upload*? Tente fazer dessa forma, também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288272/99718

Comment: Verdade! Acrescentei as duas classes ao final da pergunta!